# How to solve a Cryptarithmetic puzzle?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm studying Artificial Intelligence. So far I've read few chapters of the reference book: Artificial Intelligence, 2nd Edition, by Elaine Rich and Kevin Knight.
I'm stuck at this problem called as 'Cryptarithmetic Problem'. Can anyone provide me a video tutorial or any reference material which will explain me how to solve this particular problem using any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help. Just think of numbers as actual symbols for what they represent.  Then a letter is just another arbitrary symbol for what the math actually represents.  Almost like in Algebra where you are substituting variables for numbers.  The variables are just symbols for what the number is... Also take a look at this it might help a little bit.
http://s4.zetaboards.com/science/topic/7693756/1/

Comment: This certainly answered few of my doubts! Thanks @Sudo Andrew.